# How to turn off the sound of alert(), or is there any good alternative in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, dialog, alert

How to turn off the sound of alert(), or is there any good and simple alternative in Jquery?

Comment: That is not something that can be done in script, that is browser dependent

Answer (score 2):

You cannot turn off the sound.
You can however choose not to use alert, but use [JQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog) or [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples) for jQuery, both very cool and easy to use.